# Word or phrase for going through a few lightweight unrelated tasks with somebody at work

Tags: word-request

I want to catch up with boss to go through 5 unrelated lightweight topics, what is a good word/phrase to use for the meeting invitation? Does 'run a few errands with you' sound ok?

Answer (score 3):

"Errands" is unlikely to be correct, as it refers specifically to a type of task that involves going somewhere else, such as 'going to the shops'.

Instead, I would suggest "minor tasks", which will fit with almost any occupation.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *miscellaneous tasks*, which refers to a mix of side or possibly unrelated tasks, would be better than “errands”.